# Range Slider with Submit results as Images based from the values selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have chosen a Range Slider from CodePen https://codepen.io/cturney/pen/PowdYYo which I think is exactly what I think I need. There are a few things I would like to incorporate with  the range slider which is the "Submit" button that will show each result as images instead of numerical values. Note: Attached is an image example to help better understand what I envisioned :)

[image]

Here's the code that i have been trying to modify

```js
// I've added annotations to make this easier to follow along at home. Good luck learning and check out my other pens if you found this useful


// First let's set the colors of our sliders
const settings={
  fill: '#1abc9c',
  background: '#d7dcdf'
}

// First find all our sliders
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.range-slider');

// Iterate through that list of sliders
// ... this call goes through our array of sliders [slider1,slider2,slider3] and inserts them one-by-one into the code block below with the variable name (slider). We can then access each of wthem by calling slider
Array.prototype.forEach.call(sliders,(slider)=>{
  // Look inside our slider for our input add an event listener
//   ... the input inside addEventListener() is looking for the input action, we could change it to something like change
  slider.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', (event)=>{
    // 1. apply our value to the span
    slider.querySelector('span').innerHTML = event.target.value;
    // 2. apply our fill to the input
    applyFill(event.target);
  });
  // Don't wait for the listener, apply it now!
  applyFill(slider.querySelector('input'));
});

// This function applies the fill to our sliders by using a linear gradient background
function applyFill(slider) {
  // Let's turn our value into a percentage to figure out how far it is in between the min and max of our input
  const percentage = 100*(slider.value-slider.min)/(slider.max-slider.min);
  // now we'll create a linear gradient that separates at the above point
  // Our background color will change here
  const bg = `linear-gradient(90deg, ${settings.fill} ${percentage}%, ${settings.background} ${percentage+0.1}%)`;
  slider.style.background = bg;
}
```

```html
<p>Role Match</p>
<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="4" min="0" max="10">
  <span class="range-slider__value">4</span>
</div>

<p>Availability</p>
<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="5" min="0" max="10" step="1">
  <span class="range-slider__value">5</span>
</div>
<p>Skills Match</p>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="6" min="0" max="10">
  <span class="range-slider__value">6</span>
</div> 

<p>Custom Field Match</p>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="7" min="0" max="10">
  <span class="range-slider__value">7</span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain "each result as image"?

Comment: I meant, lets say if i press the "SUBMIT" button instead of showing a result as number, it should then show an image or images based from the numbers selected from the range sliders, example there are 4 range sliders, then it should show 4 different types of images. :) I hope i explained it better :)

Comment: Do you think its possible -Sanan Ali?

Comment: I updated my post above with a screenshot. I hope that helps. Thanks

Comment: So where is it supposed to pull those images from? _"example there are 4 range sliders, then it should show 4 different types of images"_ - so you got some sort of mapping between slider type, and specific image types? Where?

Comment: Should be from internal within the script which links from my own library :) So each numbers have different types of images, i will just add the link in the script. I hope i explained it better. So for every number shows different types of images, take for example: number 1 - image1, then number 2 so it'll show image from the library number2 so on per slide...... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of what you want to acheive. If you select first slider range to 1, 2 or 3. the image will be changed accordingly. You can do the same thing based on the other slider values. This is just to give you an idea how it will be done.
Please note that this code is not refactored.

```js
// I've added annotations to make this easier to follow along at home. Good luck learning and check out my other pens if you found this useful


// First let's set the colors of our sliders
const settings={
  fill: '#1abc9c',
  background: '#d7dcdf'
}

// First find all our sliders
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.range-slider');

// Iterate through that list of sliders
// ... this call goes through our array of sliders [slider1,slider2,slider3] and inserts them one-by-one into the code block below with the variable name (slider). We can then access each of wthem by calling slider
Array.prototype.forEach.call(sliders,(slider)=>{
  // Look inside our slider for our input add an event listener
//   ... the input inside addEventListener() is looking for the input action, we could change it to something like change
  slider.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', (event)=>{
    // 1. apply our value to the span
    slider.querySelector('span').innerHTML = event.target.value;
    // 2. apply our fill to the input
    applyFill(event.target);
  });
  // Don't wait for the listener, apply it now!
  applyFill(slider.querySelector('input'));
});

// This function applies the fill to our sliders by using a linear gradient background
function applyFill(slider) {
  // Let's turn our value into a percentage to figure out how far it is in between the min and max of our input
  const percentage = 100*(slider.value-slider.min)/(slider.max-slider.min);
  // now we'll create a linear gradient that separates at the above point
  // Our background color will change here
  const bg = `linear-gradient(90deg, ${settings.fill} ${percentage}%, ${settings.background} ${percentage+0.1}%)`;
  slider.style.background = bg;
}
const images = [{id:1, link : "https://via.placeholder.com/150"},{id:2, link : "https://via.placeholder.com/250"},{id:3, link : "https://via.placeholder.com/350"}];
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function (e){
e.preventDefault();
const selectedValueOfFirstSlider = document.getElementById("firstSlider").value;
const element = images.find((el)=>{ return el.id==selectedValueOfFirstSlider});
document.getElementById("img").src=element.link;
}
```

```html
<p>Role Match</p>
<form id="form">
<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" id="firstSlider" value="4" min="0" max="10">
  <span class="range-slider__value">4</span>
</div>

<p>Availability</p>
<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="5" min="0" max="10" step="1">
  <span class="range-slider__value">5</span>
</div>
<p>Skills Match</p>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="6" min="0" max="10">
  <span class="range-slider__value">6</span>
</div> 

<p>Custom Field Match</p>

<div class="range-slider">
  <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="7" min="0" max="10">
  <span class="range-slider__value">7</span>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button">
</form>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" width="500" id="img">
```

Comment: Will this show 4 images at once based from the 4 slides?

Comment: no, as I said this is just an example. If you select 1st slider range to 1,2 or 3 the image will be changed. You can achieve the same on other sliders. Check the code.

Comment: Ok, Thank you Sanan! :) will test that one in a bit :) Appreciate much your quick response!

Comment: Hi Sanan, How do you do it for the second slider? sorry i am still learning JS i don't know how to make a script for the second slider?

Comment: I tried adding second slide image based from the first one and didn't work, am i missing something? please see the test i am working on maybe you could shed some light for me to better understand how things works? :  https://codepen.io/archie-valderrosa/pen/RwjaRyj